# Where to look for exact effects of Spring XML namespaces configuration?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

As we know, Spring Framework has lot of configuration elements in XML namespaces such as:

- `<mvc:annotation-config/>`
- `<tx:annotation-driven/>`

Some of them do a really huge amout of work, for example: `<http>` element in Spring Security `security` namespace.

Where to look to find exact code (more than documentation says ) for all effects of introducing particular XML element?

For example - where should I look if I want to see exact Spring actions caused by ussing `<security:csrf>` element in `<security:http>` element? (which filters/interceptors/converters are added, what scope attributes becomes available etc.)

Comment: Usually I debug the code and step through the spring security sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every namespace (xsd) has a corresponding `NamespaceHandler` class somewhere in Spring. The same goes for the elements each element has a corresponding `BeanDefinitionParser`.

See the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport.html) for the available implementation in Spring itself. The Spring Security ones can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/package-frame.html).

Most Spring projects nowaways include a namespace in general somewhere in the `org.springframework.[project].config` package.

Answer (score 1):

In short you have to :

1. Author a **XML Schema file**.
2. Use NameSpaceHandler
3. Use BeanDefinitionParser
4. Registering the handler and the schema in META-INF

Refer [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/extensible-xml.html) for in-dept details

Have a look at this jar for Spring-security namespace details
**spring-security-config-x.x.X.RELEASE-sources.jar**